# Como obter o número de série do dispositivo?

Tags: android

Estou usando o seguinte código para obter o número de série do dispositivo:

```
String serial = Build.class.getField("SERIAL").get(null);
```

Porém o resultado não é o mesmo quando consulto o número de série no aparelho.

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#getSerial()) deve utilizar

```
Build.getSerial();
```

que retorna o número de série do hardware, caso esteja disponível.

Requer API level 26 e necessita da permissão `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Em versões anteriores use [Build.SERIAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL).

Se a razão para obter o Serial é querer identificar o dispositivo onde está a correr a aplicação tenha em conta o que é dito em [Práticas recomendadas para identificadores exclusivos](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html).
Também pode ser útil: [Changes to Device Identifiers in Android O](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html).

Comment: Esse método não aparece para mim na classe `Build`.

Comment: Continua me retornando um valor diferente de quando acesso no celular: *Configurações - > Sobre o dispositivo -> Status -> Número de série*

Comment: Qual está a usar `Build.SERIAL` ou `Build.getSerial();`?

Comment: `Build.SERIAL` que dá o mesmo resultado de `Build.class.getField("SERIAL").get(null)` da minha pergunta inicial

Comment: Estas são as formas que a documentação indica para obter o número de série. Se elas não funcionam será porque, talvez, o fabricante não as implementa correctamente. Se assim é não há nada a fazer, pelo menos que eu saiba.